# Cropping long strings in zsh

Tags: zsh, string, prompt

I would like to set my prompt to something like `%1~ \#`, which
would show the current directory, without the full path
(followed by `%` or `#`).  But, if the name of the directory is
long, I don't want all of it.  How would limit it to, say, 8
characters?  Is there any built-in facility for this in zsh, or
must one use some external tool?

Answer (score 3):

To truncate the directory name, try:

```
PS1='%8>..>%1~%<< %# '
```

Example: the directory `Wow longdirnameislong` will now be displayed in the prompt as:

```
Wow lo.. %
```

---

`man 1 zshmisc` says:

> CONDITIONAL SUBSTRINGS IN PROMPTS
>
> > `%<string<`
> >     `%>string>`
> >     `%[xstring]`
> >
> > Specifies  truncation behaviour for the remainder of the prompt string.  The third, deprecated, form is equivalent to `%xstringx`, i.e. x may be `<` or `>`.  The string will be displayed in place of the truncated portion of any string; note this does not undergo prompt expansion.
> >
> > The numeric argument, which in the third form may appear immediately after the `[`, specifies the maximum permitted length of the various strings that can be displayed in the prompt.  In the first two forms, this numeric argument may be negative, in which case the truncation length is determined by subtracting the absolute value of the numeric argument from the number of character positions remaining on the current prompt line.  If this results in a zero or negative length, a length of 1 is used.  In other words, a negative argument arranges that after truncation at least n characters remain before the right  margin  (left  margin for RPROMPT).
> >
> > The  forms  with  `<`  truncate  at the left of the string, and the forms with `>` truncate at the right of the string.  For example, if the current directory is `/home/pike`, the prompt `%8<..<%/` will expand to `..e/pike`.  In this string, the terminating character (`<`, `>` or `]`), or in fact any character, may be quoted by a preceding `\`; note when using print -P, however, that this must be doubled as the string is also subject to standard print processing, in addition to any backslashes removed by a double quoted string:  the worst case is therefore `print -P "%<\\\\<<..."`.
> >
> > If the string is longer than the specified truncation length, it will appear in full, completely replacing the truncated string.
> >
> > The part of the prompt string to be truncated runs to the end of the string, or to the end of the next enclosing group of the `%(` construct, or to the next truncation encountered at the same grouping level (i.e. truncations inside a `%(` are separate), which ever comes first.  In particular, a truncation with argument zero (e.g., `%<<`) marks the end of the range of the string to be truncated while turning off truncation from  there  on.  For example, the prompt `%10<...<%~%<<%#`  will print a truncated representation of the current directory, followed by a `%` or `#`, followed by a space.  Without the `%<<`, those two characters would be included in the string to be truncated.  Note that `%-0<<` is not equivalent to `%<<` but specifies that the prompt is truncated at the right margin.
> >
> > Truncation applies only within each individual line of the prompt, as delimited by embedded newlines (if any).  If the total length of any line of the prompt after truncation is greater than the  terminal  width, or  if  the part to be truncated contains embedded newlines, truncation behavior is undefined and may change in a future version of the shell.  Use `%-n(l.true-text.false-text)` to remove parts of the prompt when the available space is less than n.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple!

```
       %d
       %/     Current working directory.  If an integer follows the `%', it spec‐
              ifies a number of trailing components of the current working direc‐
              tory to show; zero means the whole path.  A negative integer speci‐
              fies leading components, i.e. %-1d specifies the first component.

       %~     As %d and %/, but if the  current  working  directory  starts  with
              $HOME,  that  part  is  replaced by a `~'. Furthermore, if it has a
              named directory as its prefix, that part is replaced by a `~'  fol‐
              lowed  by  the  name  of  the  directory, but only if the result is
              shorter than the full path; see Dynamic and Static  named  directo‐
              ries in zshexpn(1).
```

© `man zshmisc`